# PyQtGraph: legend does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqtgraph

I'm using PyQtGraph 0.10 with Py3.6 and having trouble with the following code.
I have two issues:

1) the `addLegend()` on each of the five plots just show an empty little box and

2) the `showLabel(show=False)` command is being ignored (I just want a label on the bottom plot).

```
self.win   = pg.GraphicsWindow()
self.win.clear()
for figIdx, devid in enumerate(self.norm_data.keys()):
    plot = self.win.addPlot()
    plot.plot(x=self.norm_time[devid],       y=self.norm_data[devid]      , name=devid         , pen=pg.mkPen('b', width=2), connect="finite")
    plot.plot(x=self.pkt_starts[devid].time, y=self.pkt_starts[devid].data, name="Packet start", pen=None, symbol='x' ,symbolSize=8, symbolPen="c")
    plot.plot(x=self.bad_gaps  [devid].time, y=self.bad_gaps  [devid].data, name="Seq gap"     , pen='r' , symbol=None, connect="finite")
    plot.addLegend()                   # Try to add legend
    plot.setLabel('left', "Data")
    plot.setRange(yRange=[0, 5])
    plot.setRange(xRange=[0, self.time_end])
    lr = pg.LinearRegionItem([5, 10])  # This is a mouse-draggable window on the plot
    lr.setZValue(-10)
    lr.sigRegionChanged.connect(updateRegion)
    self.region_list.append(lr)
    plot.addItem(lr)
    plot.showLabel('bottom',show=False)          # Try to turn of bottom label
    plot.getAxis('bottom').showLabel(show=False) # try again
    self.win.nextRow()

# callback for the linear region item on the plot
def updateRegion(regionItem):
    self.region_low, self.region_high = regionItem.getRegion()
```

Here is an image of the plot:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

regarding issue 1, `plot.addLegend()` should be added before `plot.plot(x,y,name)` commands

regarding issue 2, you are clearing the bottom labels for all the plots. If you want to show the bottom label for the last plot, do something like this:

```
if (figIdx != len(self.norm_data.keys())): 
    plot.showLabel('bottom',show=False) # For all other plots remove the label
else:
    plot.showLabel('bottom',show=True) # fOR THE LAST PLOT show THE BOTTOM LABEL
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Regarding 1: Yes, your correction fixed it. The addLegend() must be added before the plot command.

Comment: Regarding 2: I am now realizing that "Label" does not refer to the "Axis Number Label" but to the Label descriptor.  Then how does one remove the Axis numbers?

Comment: Okay.  Got it.  Instead of showLabels(show=False), I needed             plot.getAxis('bottom').setStyle(showValues=False).  This turned off the axis numbering.

Comment: if this helped, please upvote/accept the answer. thanks!

Comment: Regarding `addLegend()` to appear before plots, it seems this information is [not part of the documentation](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graphicsItems/plotitem.html?highlight=addlegend#pyqtgraph.PlotItem.addLegend), so your answer was very helpful.